# Close the current activity when you only have a reference to Context

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

If I have a reference to `Context`, is it possible to finish the current activity?

**I don't have the reference to current activity.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586818/finish-activity-from-custom-view-using-context/25854387#25854387

Have a look at this post :)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

yes, with a cast:

```
((Activity) ctx).finish();
```

Comment: Only if it's the current activity, otherwise the non-current activity will be finished :)

Comment: This could lead to problems if the `Context` is actually an application context.

Comment: how to do that if the context is an application context.i am running a timer thread in a class and if time finishes i want to close the current activty from that class..

Comment: I used the same in my onPostExecute().I want to close the current activity but it will be dynamic. I am calling AsyncTask from any of the Activity and getting classcast exception.  any help.

Comment: I see no problems. If it's an application context, a classcastexception will force close your app, and finish all the activities with it!

Answer (score 15):

In my Case following worked,

I need to finish my activity in a AsyncTask onPostExcute().

Where my AsyncTask class is separate public class , which has a constructor with param of Context.

```
((Activity)(mContext)).finish();
```

Only the above worked for me... Anyway I got this idea from @2red13 and @lucy answers... Thanks to all...

Comment: This is in now way different form `((Activity) mContext).finish()`.

Answer (score 14):

I know it's an old post but, perhaps it could be a good idea to call it this way:

```
if(context instanceof Activity){
                ((Activity)context).finish(); }
```

This way we make sure we don't get any unnecesary ClassCastExceptions

Comment: this didn't close the activity for me

Comment: me too, activity still running

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the running view of the Activity you want to finish (for example, you are in a click listener), you could do:

```
((Activity)getContext()).finish();
```

(With thanks to 2red13 to get me here).

Answer (score 0):

If you start the activity using:

```
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

you can call finishActivity(1) to finish any activities started with that request code, like this:

```
((Activity)getContext()).finishActivity(1);
```

In my case I need to use one in a handler postDelayed. Using this you can be sure of which activity you are finishing. Hope it helps!

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'startActivityForResult' in 'Context'

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when closing a preference activity. Here is what I did:

```
public class T2DPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
                new T2DPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class T2DPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.server_screen_preference);
            Preference testServicePreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("PREFERRED SERVER");
            testServicePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    T2DPreferenceActivity.closeActivity(getActivity());
                    return true; //returning true still makes the activity handle the change to preferences
                }
            });
        }

        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)lv.getParent();
            parent.setPadding(0, 100, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    protected static void closeActivity(Activity activity) {
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try:

```
((Activity) context.getApplicationContext()).finish();
```

Comment: Don't use this "solution"! You cannot guess (and probably you are always wrong) that your Application context is the same than your Activity.

Comment: 'if(context instanceof Activity){
                ((Activity)context).finish(); }' is a correct way