# finish activity from custom view using context

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here's my code:

```
    private void makeDialog2() {
    AlertDialog.Builder about = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    about.setTitle("You Won!");

    about.setPositiveButton("Play Again",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent playIntent2 = new Intent(getContext(),
                            PracticePlayActivity.class);
                    playIntent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    getContext().startActivity(playIntent2);
                    ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
                }
            });

    about.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg1, int arg2) {
            Intent playIntent = new Intent(getContext(),
                    PlayChooserActivity.class);
            playIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            getContext().startActivity(playIntent);
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
        }
    });

    about.show();
}
```

This code is prompted when the user loses the game and wants to retry. However when i press retry more than 4 times the application crashes. I'm suspecting a memory leak. After some testing in logcat i managed to find out that the activity is still running after retrying.

My plan is to attack this problem with two things. Recycling my drawables and ending the first activity as a whole. However, the first activity is not closing even after i call finish. Any help? (Using getContext() in other parts of my code has worked so far).

EDIT: By ending the activity does it destroy the variables automatically? or do i still need to clear the bitmaps from the Android memory? Any ideas how i can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `makeDialog2()` is declared inside an `Activity` try using `this` or `YourActivityName.this` instead of `getContext()`. If it's not, then try passing the `Context` to the method as a parameter using `this` or `YourActivityName.this` from where you call the method.

> By ending the activity does it destroy the variables automatically?

Finishing an `Activity` should destroy it and all related resources. If you start a new instance of the `Activity` later on it will re-create all its resources. Unless you use some kind of static variables - they will stay "alive" as long as your app is running.

---

> The place where this method is being called from is actually the surfaceview therefore any parameter i give it will essentially still be getContext(). Is there any way around this? I don't see why ((Activity) getContext()).finish(); isn't working

Take a look at the [documentation for the `Activity`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

As you can see `Context` is a superclass of `Activity` - meaning that every `Activity` is a `Context` but not every `Context` is an `Activity`. In other words `((Activity) getContext()).finish();` might cause a `ClassCastException`.

What you could do to verify that the `Context` you get is in fact also an `Activity` is do a check like this:

```
if( getContext() instanceof Activity )
   Log.e( "TAG", "getContext() returns an Activity!" );
```

Add that right before the you call `finish()` and check if LogCat agrees that its an `Activity`.

Comment: thanks, not only did you help me but you explained a question :)

Comment: actually sorry about this but there is a problem. The place where this method is being called from is actually the surfaceview therefore any parameter i give it will essentially still be getContext(). Is there any way around this? I don't see why ((Activity) getContext()).finish(); isn't working

Comment: I added some more stuff to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Perhaps it is a bug but i had to first call the class name before the getContext() function. Perhaps its a bug with the dialog function or an error in my code structure.

```
ClassName.this.getContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround to this problem, and avoid that ClassCastException.

First override the getApplicationContext() method in your Activity so that it returns the current instance

```
@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() { return this; }
```

This method will still return the instance with a Context reference type, but you can now cast it to YourActivity before passing it onto your custom view.

```
 new CustomView((YourActivity) getApplicationContext());
```

Also, make sure you reference this with `YourActivity` instead of `Context` in your custom view.

Hope this post helps anyone else who comes across this :)