# Intent from AsyncTask startActivity not working (FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have the following `AsyncTask`. In the onPostExecute method I am trying to start another activity using the Intent. However, I noticed that the new activity doesn't start and the `finish()` line is simply called closing the current activity. I do not know what the cause of this can be.

```
   private void uploadImage(final String city, final String offset, final int currImage, final View itemView, final Animation animation) {
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private Context context;

        public UploadImage(Context context){
            this.context=context;
        }
      //  ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("city", city);
            data.put("offset",offset);
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(SL_URL, data);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //loading = ProgressDialog.show(SlideShow.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...", true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
           // loading.dismiss();
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject a = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    imageDisplayerArrayList.add(new ImageDisplayer(a.getString("user_id"),a.getString("image"),a.getString("longitude"),a.getString("latitude"),a.getString("city"),a.getString("geo_name_id"),a.getString("description"),a.getString("score"),a.getString("Categories")));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            itemView.clearAnimation();
            itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (imageDisplayerArrayList.size() > 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SlideShow.class);
                intent.putExtra("key",imageDisplayerArrayList);
                intent.putExtra("city", city);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) context).finish();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No new content available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();                }



        }}
    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage(this);
    ui.execute(city);


}
```

PARCELABLE IMAGEDISPLAYER CLASS:

```
public class ImageDisplayer implements Parcelable {
private String user_id;
private String image;
private String longitude;

private ImageDisplayer(Parcel in) {
    this.user_id = in.readString();
    this.image = in.readString();
    this.longitude = in.readString();
    this.latitude = in.readString();
    this.city = in.readString();
    this.geo_name_id = in.readString();
    this.description = in.readString();
    this.score = in.readString();
    this.categories = in.readString();
}
public ImageDisplayer(String user_id, String image, String longitude, String latitude, String city, String geo_name_id, String description, String score, String categories) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.image = image;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.city = city;
    this.geo_name_id = geo_name_id;
    this.description = description;
    this.score = score;
    this.categories = categories;
}

public String getUser_id() {

    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getGeo_name_id() {
    return geo_name_id;
}

public void setGeo_name_id(String geo_name_id) {
    this.geo_name_id = geo_name_id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public String getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public void setCategories(String categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

private String latitude;
private String city;
private String geo_name_id;
private String description;
private String score;
private String categories;

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(user_id);
    dest.writeString(image);
    dest.writeString(longitude);
    dest.writeString(latitude);
    dest.writeString(city);
    dest.writeString(geo_name_id);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(score);
    dest.writeString(categories);

}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ImageDisplayer> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<ImageDisplayer>() {

    // This simply calls our new constructor (typically private) and
    // passes along the unmarshalled `Parcel`, and then returns the new object!
    @Override
    public ImageDisplayer createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ImageDisplayer(in);
    }

    // We just need to copy this and change the type to match our class.
    @Override
    public ImageDisplayer[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ImageDisplayer[size];
    }
};
```

}

SLIDESHOW

```
public class SlideShow extends Activity {

private ArrayList<ImageDisplayer> imageDisplayerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private String city;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_show);
    imageDisplayerArrayList = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key");
    TextView time_rem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_rem);
    time_rem.bringToFront();
    city = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");
    slideshow(imageDisplayerArrayList, 0, 0);
}


private void uploadImage2(final String city, final String offset, final int currImage) {
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        //ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("city", city);
            data.put("offset",offset);
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(SL_URL, data);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
           // loading = ProgressDialog.show(SlideShow.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...", true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
          //  loading.dismiss();
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject a = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    imageDisplayerArrayList.add(new ImageDisplayer(a.getString("user_id"),a.getString("image"),a.getString("longitude"),a.getString("latitude"),a.getString("city"),a.getString("geo_name_id"),a.getString("description"),a.getString("score"),a.getString("Categories")));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }}
    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
    ui.execute(city);


}

public Bitmap ConvertToImage(String image){
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(image, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }

public void slideshow(ArrayList<ImageDisplayer> a, final int currImage, final int offset) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picturedisplay);
    int currphoto = 0;

    final long DELAY = 300; // milliseconds
    final long VIEW_TIME = 10000;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final TimerTask update_time = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SlideShow.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView time_rem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_rem);
                    int timeRem = Integer.parseInt(time_rem.getText().toString());
                    timeRem--;
                    time_rem.setText(Integer.toString(timeRem));
                }});
        }};
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask() {
                int i = currImage;
                int off = 0;
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SlideShow.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (i < imageDisplayerArrayList.size()) {
                                TextView time_rem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_rem);
                                time_rem.setText("10");
                                Bitmap myBitmap = ConvertToImage(imageDisplayerArrayList.get(i).getImage());
                                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picturedisplay);
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                Integer.toString(imageDisplayerArrayList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                               .show();
                                i++;
                                off = (int)(Math.rint(Math.ceil((double) i / 10) * 10));
                                if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 10 != 0) {
                                    uploadImage2(city,Integer.toString(off),i);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                update_time.cancel();
                                Intent i = new Intent(SlideShow.this,ViewScreen.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                                                                  }});
                }


            },
            DELAY,VIEW_TIME
    );
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(update_time, 0, 1000);

}

}
```

UPDATE

This is caused by the following error `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!` as my image arraylist exceeds the 1MB limit. Can someone please help me create an alternative solution to passing this arraylist between the two activities?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise the Toast is displayed, also the `finish()` is called. My ImageDisplayer class implements parcelable, could this be an issue with that maybe?

Comment: Only use this `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Could you double check that the if block is run by putting a break point just in case?

Comment: I used that before, had the same behaviour

Comment: @Khanal it is run, I checked by putting a log statement inside. Could the problem be caused by the extras I put?

Comment: unlikely, it would have exceptioned if that were the case.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that its called from within an inner class (the asynctask)

Comment: How about you pass the reference to the activity into the task within a constructor and and do a null check and call a method that launches the new intent but from the activity itself ( a public method in activity that does it.)

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing already by passing `this` in the constructor?

Comment: are you getting any logs, because there may be a case of exception with the extras you added...

Comment: I updated the question with the parcelable class that I'm using for the arraylist. I'm not sure if I implemented this right, in case the issue is with this I would be grateful if someone could check it for me

Comment: you are. Sorry didn't realize that duh. So why dont you have a public method in the activity that launches another intent and just call that from te asyntack?

Comment: ok will check your parcelable implemention.

Comment: if you call `startActivity` and nothing happens, there has to be a log. post the log

Comment: Parcelable Implementation looks good.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8587104/5662475) it may help you .

Comment: Please show the `SlideShow.java` file, it looks that activity has some problem.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed updated

Comment: what about adding `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: Please check the update

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you have to fetch the `ParcelableArrayList` 
`imagesArrayList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");`

**Secondly**, You are doing too much I/O work in `slide show` function which is causing delay

**Thirdly** You are doing bitmaps work and displaying bitmaps on `Ui Thread`, you have to move your bitmaps work off the ui thread,  its worth using Universal Image Loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code. and when you call asynctask pass activity context thats it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(((Activity) context), SlideShow.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key",imageDisplayerArrayList);
intent.putExtra("city", city);
((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Now you retrieve your array list in another activity like this

imageDisplayerArrayList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");

If you are passing bitmap in list don't do that just pass url in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pair of `ParcelFileDescriptor`s using [createSocketPair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#createPipe()) and pass one of the objects to the activity by putting the object into the intent. Then you can pass data by creating `File[Input|Output]Stream object` from the underlying `FileDescriptor` for the parcel file descriptor. (use[getFileDescriptor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#getFileDescriptor()) to obtain FileDescriptor)