# Is it always safe to cast Context to Activity within View

Tags: android

May I know, is it safe for me to always cast `Context` to `Activity` within a `View`?

```
View {
    Activity activity = (Activity)this.getContext();
}
```

So far, it works fine all the moment. I was wondering, is there any edge cases that the above code will fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't think of such case, I think it is not such a great idea for two reasons:

1. **Why** would you want to do that, when do you explicitly need Activity?
2. What if tomorrow this will be changed, and there will be other context for `View`?

Comment: **1.** There are [situations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5376772) in which the caller can't an Activity as a parameter. **2.** Android is pretty good in keeping backward compatibility (which I can't say about its development tools). IMHO @lulumeya's answer is the correct answer to be accepted.

Comment: `ContextThemeWrapper` certainly adds a whole new level of nonsense to it. I've heard you can access the Activity using `getBaseContext()` then.

Answer (score 57):

As I know, It is not always safe because, the context also can be passed from os to a Service, BroadcastReceiver, etc. But, almost of case, that is not a problem. just check with this code

```
if(context instanceof Activity)
```

and feel free to use.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use following snippet:

```
/**
 * Get activity instance from desired context.
 */
public static Activity getActivity(Context context) {
    if (context == null) return null;
    if (context instanceof Activity) return (Activity) context;
    if (context instanceof ContextWrapper) return getActivity(((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext());
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically, Views can be created with any Context (via the `LayoutInflater`)

So unless you are super sure that your Views are only instantiated by Activities, I wouldn't suggest this. Doing this is not a clean idea.