# Custom View unable to get Activity handle from View.getContext

Tags: android, android-activity, android-custom-view, android-context

I have a custom view inside an activity, which i am launching with an Application context.

When i call the `View.getContext()` from within my `CustomView` and try to cast it:

```
Activity activity = (Acitivity)View.getContext();
```

It gives an error that cannot cast the `Context` from `Application` to `Activity`.

Has someone faced this problem before ??? please help

Comment: If you're passing the application `Context` to your view why do you try to use as an `Activity` `Context`?

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273218/is-it-always-safe-to-cast-context-to-activity-within-view

Answer (score 3):

As Romain Guy says in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3901704/2029566) post, there is no guarantee that the `Context` used by your `View` is an `Activity`. Also, if you are using the `Applcation` `Context` you cannot cast it to the `Activity` `Context`; they are different. This [link](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=78ad4cb95e-Android_Weekly_64&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-78ad4cb95e-328260729) gives a great explanation of all the different flavors of `Context`

Comment: I know that, but i need to pass in parameters to my Custom View from the activity. e.g. the Activity wants to tell the custom-view to change its background color and the view should do something in it onDraw()

Comment: You may want to try to create an interface in your `Activity` and have the `View` implement it. You can set some boolean member inside the interface implementation and then call `invalidate()`. Inside `onDraw()` check to see if the boolean is true and update the `View`'s background.