# Start a new Android Activity from inside the OpenGL main loop

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity

I have created a class that extends Activity that will prompt the user to pick an email client and send an email. I can get this class to work perfectly if I call it from within onCreate of my MainActivity. However, once OpenGL starts, I don't know how to start this Activity once the OpenGL loop has taken over. I have tried passing the MainActivity context to my OpenGL thread and starting the email activity like:

```
// This starts a new activity and sends the email with the text file
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(context, SendEmailActivity.class);
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/MoCap/TomsFile.txt";
emailIntent.putExtra("filePath", filePath);
emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

And it will launch my activity just fine. However, after I'm done sending the email, I come back to an OpenGL 1285 memory out of bounds error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here:
[Finishing an Activity from a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376730/android-finish-activity-context)

I needed to add `((Activity) context).finish();` after I called `startActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use GLSurfaceView to use OpenGL. If it is so, Please try GLSurfaceView.onPause() before going to email Activity. And when come back to Activity on OpenGL, call GLSurfaceView.onResume();

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, I am using a package called jMonkey that abstracts a lot of the core OpenGL stuff (like onPause() and onResume()) away from the user. I have tried looking into the guts of how it works and it looks like it starts it's own thread with OGLESContext and leaves the main Android Activity behind. This is why I tried to pass the context and start it up with that, but I don't know why I get the OpenGL 1285 error when I do this. I assume that has something to do with blocking the main update thread?