# Unable to find a method similar to finish() in Android Wear's activity

Tags: android, wear-os

Currently, I'm making an android wear(sony smart watch3) app and I'm having trouble implementing a method to finish the android wear application. I tried to find a method similar to finish() however, I cannot find one. I've read contents about android wear in the following site but still can't find what I'm looking for. Is there some way to finish an activity or the app it'self? If possible I want to finish the app by code, not by some default swipes.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/DismissOverlayView.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5376772/8342742) thread.

You can do this with a cast.

```
((Activity) ctx).finish();
```